# Where to ask questions, that are related to 2 Different sub-Sites?

Tags: support, questions, specific-question, duplicate-questions

I have a question about how to mount best a DSLR camera to an aeroplane.
But now I'm wondering, where I would have to ask it? The camera does also have to be controlled from inside the plane.

In the aviation section, because they have the knowledge about aeroplanes, structure and aerodynamics.

In the photography, because they have experience with mounting cameras to all sort of things (GoPro)

Arduino/Raspery Pi - For how you would control the camera.

somewhere else?

I believe posting it to all sites is not a good answer, but how could I reach all the people? I believe duplicate questions wouldn't be a good Idea.

I know there has been a similar question before (where they said, ask similar questions on different networks and point to each other, but I doubt that this would be helpful in this case.

What should I do?

Are there some tags, where you could tag another Stack Exchange community, to include them as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *do* post to all relevant sites, but you don't post the *same* question to each.

As it is your question seems very broad, you need to cut it down and ask more specific questions relevant to the site's scope. You can explain the whole problem for context, but focus the question on the area that site covers.

For example;

- On [Aviation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/), you focus your question on how you would hook up the camera through the structure of the plane, or how the camera would affect aerodynamics.
- On [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/), you ask how to best capture images from the air, how to compensate for the high speed movement of the plane etc.
- On [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), you ask specifically how to use your Raspberry Pi to remotely control a camera.

Note, I'm not active on any of those sites so don't take those examples literally.

The important thing is; questions should be specific and focused. If your question seems like it would fit on multiple unrelated sites then it is too broad.

Comment: *If your question seems like it would fit on multiple unrelated sites then it is too broad.* That is a great rule-of-thumb